# StencilJS - Insert element in body instead of component

Tags: javascript, jsx, stenciljs

I'm building a component in StencilJS which has a tooltip.

I would like to append this tooltip's markup in the document.body instead of my component, as it runs into issues when the component is wrapped in an element with overflow:hidden (the tooltip gets cut off)

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have the exact same component in React, and I managed to fix it by using `ReactDOM.createPortal(tooltip, document.body)` but I can't seem to be able to find a similar solution in Stencil (plus, the documentation is quite basic).

I also tried manually generating the elements with `document.createElement` but it's a pain and too verbose, and I have a couple of icons as components I would like to include.

An alternative solution would be a way to transform JSX into actual markup I can then use by doing `document.body.append(tooltip)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createElement` is probably the easiest and most flexible way.

[Ionic does this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/utils/overlays.ts#L46) when creating overlays (alerts, modals, popovers etc.).

```
const tooltip = document.createElement('my-tooltip');
tooltip.content = 'Tooltip Content <my-icon name="foo"/>';
document.body.append(tooltip);
```

This way you can easily pass properties to `tooltip`, including where the tooltip should be positioned ([example in Ionic's `popover` component](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/components/popover/animations/md.enter.ts)).

Instead of passing the HTML as a property (and using it via `<div innerHTML={this.content}>`) you can also pass the name of a component to be included which the tooltip then creates with `createElement`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I guess if this is the way Ionic is doing it, it should be the way forward. Also, I forgot I could do `document.createElement` on a custom component :facepalm: